# Is it possible to connect React JS with SQLite database?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite

Is it possible to connect React JS with SQLite database without any node.js or express ?
If yes, please give me an example or provide some resource link.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Is possible to do this using sql.js. I had no luck with the sqlite3 module.

Here is the example I used: https://github.com/sql-js/react-sqljs-demo